# EF Core one-to-many by navigation property (not by primary key)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I would like to reuse one-to-many relationship (in the example Group-Value), but also provide "skip" navigation property to access the collection (values) of the group (referenced one-to-many relationship). Hopefully, the example below with EntityA and EntityB (see the commented property) will explain what I'd like to do:

```
public class Value {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Group {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    prop ICollection<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

public class EntityA {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    
    // Somehow directly reference Values from Group
    public ICollectionValue> Values; { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    
    // Somehow directly reference Values from Group
    public ICollectionValue> Values; { get; set; }
}
```

The closes solution I came to is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>() // same for EntityB
    .HasMany(p => p.Values)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.Id)
    .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.GroupId);
```

But the migration adds a new column named GroupId1 to the table, ignoring the existing GroupId.
Any help on this matter how to achieve it is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just add a property like `public ICollection<Value> Values => this.Group.Values;`? Then you can access the values "directly".

Comment: I could, but that means every time I want to access Values I need to do .Include(p => p.Group).ThenInclude(p => p.Values), merging two tables instead of one, which is completely unnecessary. This is why I am doing this.

Comment: What is the problem with `.Include(p => p.Group).ThenInclude(p => p.Values)`? You have to load the entities anyway when you want to read/use them.

Comment: The short answer is - you can't. EFC navigation properties represent direct physical FK relationships. Skip, logical etc. navigation "helpers" are not supported.